# how can i show Gaussian cube file with vtk?

Tags: c++, vtk

I have a file with .cube [format](https://ufile.io/3oqj7fj1). I want show it with vtk as such as this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmlp0.jpg). how can i show this file with C++ vtk?

Comment: Unclear. Are requesting some code? Did you read the help pages? Seems like you are not familiar on how things work here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stop working with VTK some years ago, but I think you're searching for a Gaussian Cube file reader. Some research leads here:
https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/annotated.html

In the provided link, you can find some official examples, in particular there are two classes that I think could help you:

- [vtkGaussianCubeReader2.h](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/vtkGaussianCubeReader2_8h_source.html): Read a Gaussian Cube file and output a vtkMolecule object and a vtkImageData
- [vtkGaussianCubeReader.h](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/vtkGaussianCubeReader_8h_source.html): Read ASCII Gaussian Cube Data files

Hope these can help.